# Can YUIs DataTable have resizeable but not moveable columns?

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui

I have implemented column resizing with [YUIs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) [DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) as demonstrated in this example:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_complex_clean.html

Is there anyway to enable column resizing without column moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set "resizable" to true in your column definitions (it defaults to [false](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Column.html#property_resizeable)). Your link has an example of this on line #79.

Don't set draggableColumns in the datatable configuration (it defaults to [false](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html#config_draggableColumns)). This is done in the example on line #99.